# how can i optimize this javascript code for canvas html5 to make it run smooth in firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this big problem that when i run this javascript code used in canvas html5 in firefox it lags badly and the images blink, but in google chrome and internet explorer the performance is better. I really need the procedure, so I wont get lost. The code is about projectile motion. I need to mention that i need the conditions im using. (Note: there is a fence function in javascript that i made that makes firefox lag so much to the point that is freezes)

This is my html:

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="img/logo-ute.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" />
        <title>Simulacion</title>
        <meta charset="windows-1252">
        <link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mp2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contenedor">
            <div class="encabezado">
                <div class="contenedor2">
                    <div id="imagenes">
                        <img id="img" src="img/logo_facu.png" width="500" height="200"/>
                        <img id="img2" src="img/logo-ute.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="contenedor3">
                    <h2>SIMULACIÓN</h2>
                    <section id="cajalienzo">
                        <canvas id="lienzo" width=1000 height=500>
                            El navegador no soporta canvas
                        </canvas>
                    </section>
                    <div id="seccion">
                        <div id="simular">
                            <form id="inicio_sim">
                                <div>
                                    <label>Angulo de Elevación: &nbsp;</label><input id="angulo" type="number"  name="angulo" min="1" max="90" value="45"  style="width:50px" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);"><span> º</span> 
                                    <label>&nbsp;Velocidad Inicial: &nbsp;</label><input id="velocidadin" type="number"  name="velocidad" min="20" max="100" value="50" step="0.5" style="width:50px" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return justNumbers2(event);"><span>&nbsp; m/s</span></br>
                                </div>
                                <div id="botones_sim">
                                    <button id="pausar" name="btnpausar" type="button" value="pausar" onclick="fun_pausar()"><span class="iconic icon-pause2"></span> PAUSAR </button>
                                    <button id="iniciar" name="btniniciar" type="button" value="iniciar" onclick="fun_simular()"><span class="iconic icon-play3"></span> INICIAR </button>
                                    <button id="reiniciar" name="btnReiniciar" type="button" value="reiniciar" onclick="fun_reiniciar()"><span class="iconic icon-spinner11"></span> REINICIAR </button>
                                </div>
                            </form> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="mostrar">
                        <form id="resultado">
                            <div>
                                <label>Posicion-x: </label><input id="posx" type="text" readonly name="distancia-horizontal" value="0.00"><span>&nbsp; m</span>
                                <label>&nbsp; Velocidad-x: </label><input id="vx" type="text" readonly name="velocidad en x" value="0.00" autocomplete="off"><span>&nbsp; m/s</span>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label>Posicion-y: &nbsp;</label><input id="posy" type="text" readonly name="distancia-vertical" value="0.00"><span>&nbsp; m</span>
                                <label>&nbsp; Velocidad-y: </label><input id="vy" type="text" readonly name="velocidad en y" value="0.00"><span>&nbsp; m/s</span>
                                <label>Tiempo: &nbsp;</label><input id="tiempo" type="text" readonly name="tiempo" value="0.00"><span>&nbsp; s</span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <h1></h1>
                        <div id="botones">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a id="regresar" href="Teoria.html"><span class="iconic icon-circle-left"></span> ANTERIOR PAGINA</a></li>
                                <li><a id="seguir" href="Bibliografia.html"><span class="iconic icon-circle-right"></span> SIGUIENTE PAGINA</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <h1></h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my javascript:

```
var canvas;
var context;
var tiempo = 0;
var tiempo2 = 999999;
var temp;
var temp2;
var x2;
var y2;
var angulogrados;
var x;
var y;

//Detects the browswer to skip the fence function in firefox
function navegador(){
    c=navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome");
    f=navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox");
    m8=navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE 8.0");
    m9=navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE 9.0");
    if (c>-1){
        brwsr = "Chrome";
        context.save();
        sombras2();
        cerca();
        context.restore();
    }
    else if(f>-1){
        if(temp2==true)
        {   
            brwsr = "Firefox";
            temp2=false;
        }
    }else if (m9>-1){
        brwsr ="MSIE 9.0";
        context.save();
        sombras2();
        cerca();
        context.restore();
    }else if (m8>-1){
        brwsr ="MSIE 8.0";
        context.save();
        sombras2();
        cerca();
        context.restore();
    }
    else
    {
        context.save();
        sombras2();
        cerca();
        context.restore();
    }
}

//loads this functions first
window.onload=fun_iniciar;

function fun_iniciar(){
    //objeto canvas
    canvas = document.getElementById("lienzo");
    //crea un conexto del objeto canvas
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    temp2=true;
    //llama a la funcion que dibuja el fondo del canvas
    fondo();
    // puntos de iniclizacion del proyectil
    x=25;
    y=canvas.height-20;
    //calls the functions to draw the vectors and calculate the proyectile speed and position 
    dibupun(0,0);
    //inicializa los valores
    angulogrados=0;
    velocidad=0;
    //tiempo real
    intervalo=50;
    tiempo=intervalo/1000;
    y1=0;
    vx=0;
    vxy=0;
    vy=0;
    x2=20;
    y2=80;
    document.getElementById("reiniciar").disabled = true;
}
//se activa cuando el boton inicar se aplasta
function fun_simular(){
    document.getElementById("reiniciar").disabled = false;
    // se hace una repetecion de la funcion fun_play
    interval=setInterval(fun_play,intervalo);
}
// aqui se va a dar todos los calculos para dibujar el proyectil
function fun_play(){
    //llama a la funcion que dibuja el fondo del canvas

    fondo();
    //desavilita los comando de insertar un ganulo y la velocidad a que no cambie la trayectoria durante la simulacion
    document.getElementById("angulo").setAttribute("disabled","true");
    document.getElementById("velocidadin").setAttribute("disabled","true");
    //extrae el angulo y  la velocidad
    angulogrados=document.getElementById("angulo").value;  
    anguloradianes=angulogrados*Math.PI/180;
    velocidadi=document.getElementById("velocidadin").value;
    //calcula las velocidades iniciales en x,y
    velocidadiy=velocidadi*Math.sin(anguloradianes);
    velocidadix=velocidadi*Math.cos(anguloradianes);
    //calcula las pox- y la pos-y
    x=(velocidadi*Math.cos(anguloradianes)*tiempo)+25;
    y1=((velocidadiy*tiempo)+((0.5)*(-9.81)*(Math.pow(tiempo,2))));
    //calcula la pos-y para ubicarla en el canvas
    y=(-y1-25)+canvas.height;
    //calcula la velocidad final en y la velocidad final en x es la velocidad inicial en x
    velocidadfy=velocidadiy+((-9.81)*tiempo);
    // devuelve los resultados de la posicion y la velocidad
    document.getElementById("posx").value=((x-25.00).toFixed(2));
    if(y1<0)
    {
        document.getElementById("posy").value=((0).toFixed(2));
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("posy").value=((y1).toFixed(2));
    }
    document.getElementById("vx").value=velocidadix.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("vy").value=velocidadfy.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("tiempo").value =(tiempo).toFixed(2);
    // la animacion se detiene cuando la altura es negativa o 0
    if(y1<=0)
    {
       document.getElementById("angulo").removeAttribute("disabled");
       document.getElementById("velocidadin").removeAttribute("disabled");
       window.clearInterval(interval);
       tiempo2=tiempo;
       temp=true;
    }
    document.getElementById("iniciar").disabled = true;

    //adds the time 
    tiempo=tiempo+0.05;
    //manda a dibujar con los valores calculados
    dibupun(velocidadix,velocidadfy);
}

//draws the background
function fondo()
{
    var imageObj2 = new Image();

    imageObj2.onload = function() {
        context.moveTo(0, 0);
        context.drawImage(imageObj2, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    };
    imageObj2.src = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aErlwl1hEHw/sddefault.jpg';

    var cloud = new Image();

    cloud.onload = function(){
        context.moveTo(0, 0);
        context.drawImage(cloud, 0, 0, canvas.width/2.1, canvas.height/2);
    };
    cloud.src = 'http://silveiraneto.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/cloud.png';
}

function sombras()
{
    context.shadowOffsetY = 25;
    context.shadowOffsetX = 20;
    context.shadowBlur = 0.5;
    context.shadowBlur = 0.5;
    context.shadowColor = 'rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.6)';
}

function sombras2()
{
    context.shadowOffsetY = 25;
    context.shadowOffsetX = 20;
    context.shadowBlur = 0.5;
    context.shadowBlur = 0.5;
    context.shadowColor = 'rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.1)';
}

function sombras3()
{
    context.shadowOffsetY = 25;
    context.shadowOffsetX = 20;
    context.shadowBlur = 0.5;
    context.shadowBlur = 0.5;
    context.shadowColor = 'rgba(50, 50, 50, 0)';
}

function dibujar_calc()
{
    context.beginPath();
    context.font = "15pt Calibri";
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.textBaseline = "middle";
}

//pausa la animacion
function fun_pausar(){
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    document.getElementById("iniciar").disabled = false;
}
//draws the vectors
function dibupun(vx,vy){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.moveTo(x, y);

        context.save();
        trazaraltura(vy);
        context.restore();

        context.save();
        sombras3();
        velocidadx(vx, vy);
        context.restore();

        context.save();
        sombras3();
        velocidady(vy);
        context.restore();

        navegador();

        context.save();
        context.beginPath();

        flechay(vy);
        flechax(vx, vy);
        flechaxy(vx, vy);

        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeStyle = "blue"; 
        context.stroke();

        context.restore();

        if((x>900 && tiempo>11) || (x>900))
        {
            context.drawImage(imageObj, canvas.width-100-14, y-14, 30, 30);
        }
        else
        {
            context.drawImage(imageObj, x-14, y-14, 30, 30);
        }
    };
    imageObj.src = 'http://www.dpcdsb.org/NR/rdonlyres/132B2859-0F1F-42F6-BE18-A151ABF439BE/105710/basketball.png';
    sombras();
}

//draws the arrow in x
function flechax(vx, vy){
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    if((x>canvas.width-100 && tiempo>11) || (x>canvas.width-100))
    {
        context.moveTo(canvas.width-100, y);
        context.lineTo(canvas.width-100+vx, y);
        context.lineTo(canvas.width-100+vx-10, -5+y);
        context.lineTo(canvas.width-100+vx-10, 5+y);
        context.lineTo(canvas.width-100+vx, y);
        context.fill();  
    }
    else
    {
        context.moveTo(x, y);
        context.lineTo(x+vx, y);
        context.lineTo(x+vx-10, -5+y);
        context.lineTo(x+vx-10, 5+y);
        context.lineTo(x+vx, y);
        context.fill();
    }
}
//draws arrow in y
function flechay(vy){
    context.lineWidth = 5;

    if((x>canvas.width-100 && tiempo>11) || (x>canvas.width-100))
    {
        context.moveTo(canvas.width-100, y);
    }
    else
    {
        context.moveTo(x, y);
    }

    if((x>canvas.width-100 && tiempo>11) || (x>canvas.width-100))
    {
        if(vy>0)
        {
            context.lineTo(canvas.width-100, y-vy);
            context.lineTo(-5+canvas.width-100, y-vy+10);
            context.lineTo(5+canvas.width-100, y-vy+10);
            context.lineTo(canvas.width-100, y-vy);
        }
        else if(vy<0)
        {
            context.lineTo(canvas.height+400, y-vy);
            context.lineTo(-5+canvas.height+400, y-vy-10);
            context.lineTo(5+canvas.height+400, y-vy-10);
            context.lineTo(canvas.height+400, y-vy);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(vy>0)
        {
            context.lineTo(x, canvas.height-vy-y1-25);
            context.lineTo(-5+x, canvas.height-vy-y1-15);
            context.lineTo(5+x, canvas.height-vy-y1-15);
            context.lineTo(x, canvas.height-vy-y1-25);
        }
        else if(vy<0)
        {
            context.lineTo(x, y-vy);
            context.lineTo(-5+x, y-vy-10);
            context.lineTo(5+x, y-vy-10);
            context.lineTo(x, y-vy);
        }
    }
    context.fill();
}

 //draws an arrow in xy(I cant make it work correctly)
function flechaxy(vx, vy){
    context.lineWidth = 5;

    if((x>canvas.width-100 && tiempo>11) || (x>canvas.width-100))
    {
        context.moveTo(canvas.width-100, y);
        context.lineTo(canvas.width-100+vx, y);
        context.lineTo(canvas.width-100+vx-10, -5+y);
        context.lineTo(canvas.width-100+vx-10, 5+y);
        context.lineTo(canvas.width-100+vx, y);
        context.fill();  
    }
    else
    {
        if(vy>0)
        {
            if(y>0)
            {
                context.moveTo(x, y);
                context.lineTo(x+x2, y-vx+5-y2+vy);
                context.lineTo(x+x2-5, y-vx-5-y2+vy);
                context.lineTo(x+x2+5, y-vx-5-y2+vy);
                context.lineTo(x+x2, y-vx+5-y2+vy);
                context.fill();
                x2=x2+0.35;
                y2=y2-1.5;
            }
        }
        else if(vy<0)
        {
            if(y>0)
            {
                context.moveTo(x, y);
                context.lineTo(x+x2, y+vx+y2-vy);
                context.lineTo(x+x2+5, y+vx-10+y2-vy);
                context.lineTo(x+x2-5, y+vx-10+y2-vy);
                context.lineTo(x+x2, y+vx+y2-vy);
                context.fill();
                x2=x2-0.35;
                y2=y2+1.5;
            }
        }
    }
}

//draws the fences (in firefox this gets ignored because the code lags so much that it doesnt run)
function cerca(){
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.beginPath();
    if((x>canvas.width-100 && tiempo>11) || (x>canvas.width-100))
    {
        context.moveTo(canvas.width, y);
    }
    else
    {
        context.moveTo(x, y);
    }

    if((x>canvas.width-100 && tiempo>11) || (x>canvas.width-100))
    {
        for(i=0;i<canvas.width-199;i+=200)
        {
            context.fillStyle = "#A4A4A4";
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = 2;
            context.strokeStyle = "#A4A4A4"; 
            context.rect(-x+i+canvas.width+90, 420,  10, 80);
            if(i>canvas.width-200)
            {
                context.globalAlpha=0;
                context.rect(-x+i+canvas.width+90, 420,  10, 80);
            }
        }
        context.beginPath();
        for(i=0;i<canvas.width-399;i+=200)
        {
            context.fillStyle = "#0B614B";
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = 2;
            context.strokeStyle = "#0B614B"; 
            context.rect(-x+i+canvas.width+100, 430,  190, 5);
            context.rect(-x+i+canvas.width+100, 450,  190, 5);
            context.rect(-x+i+canvas.width+100, 470,  190, 5);
            if(i>=canvas.width-400)
            {
                context.globalAlpha=0;
                context.fillRect(-x+i+canvas.width+100, 430,  190, 5);
                context.fillRect(-x+i+canvas.width+10, 450,  190, 5);
                context.fillRect(-x+i+canvas.width+10, 470,  190, 5);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<canvas.width-199;i+=200)
        {
            context.fillStyle = "#A4A4A4";
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = 2;
            context.strokeStyle = "#A4A4A4"; 
            context.rect(i+210, 420,  10, 80);
            if(i>canvas.width-200)
            {
                context.globalAlpha=0;
                context.rect(i+210, 420,  10, 80);
            }
        }
        context.beginPath();
        for(i=0;i<canvas.width-399;i+=200)
        {
            context.fillStyle = "#0B614B";
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = 2;
            context.strokeStyle = "#0B614B"; 
            context.rect(i+220, 430,  190, 5);
            context.rect(i+220, 450,  190, 5);
            context.rect(i+220, 470,  190, 5);
            if(i>=canvas.width-400)
            {
                context.globalAlpha=0;
                context.fillRect(i+220, 430,  190, 5);
                context.fillRect(i+220, 450,  190, 5);
                context.fillRect(i+220, 470,  190, 5);
            }
        }
    }
    context.stroke();
}

//shows the x velocity along with y position and x position in the canvas
function velocidadx(vx, vy){

    if(tiempo > 0.1)
    {
        dibujar_calc();
        ancho2=x-25.00;
        altura2=canvas.height-y-20.00;

        if((x>canvas.width-200 && tiempo>11) || (x>canvas.width-200))
        {   
            if(tiempo > tiempo2-0.001)
            {
                trazaraltura(vy);
                context.fillText("Posicion-y: "+(0).toFixed(2)+" m", canvas.width-210+100, y-100);
            }
            else
            {
                trazaraltura(vy);
                context.fillText("Posicion-y: "+altura2.toFixed(2)+" m", canvas.width-210+100, y-100);
            }
            context.fillText("Posicion-x: "+ancho2.toFixed(2)+" m", canvas.width-210+100, y-130);
            context.fillText("Vx: "+vx.toFixed(2)+" m/s", canvas.width-210+100, y-40)
        }
        else
        {
            if(temp==true)
            {
                trazaraltura(vy);
                context.fillText("Posicion-y: "+(0).toFixed(2)+" m", x+100, y-100);
            }
            else
            {
                context.fillText("Posicion-y: "+altura2.toFixed(2)+" m", x+100, y-100);
            }
            context.fillText("Posicion-x: "+ancho2.toFixed(2)+" m", x+100, y-130);
            context.fillText("Vx: "+vx.toFixed(2)+" m/s", x+100, y-40)
        }
    }
}
//shows the y velocity in the canvas
function velocidady(vy){

    if(tiempo > 0.1)
    {
        dibujar_calc();
        if((x>canvas.width-200 && tiempo>11) || (x>canvas.width-200))
        {
            context.fillText("Vy: "+vy.toFixed(2)+" m/s", canvas.width-210+100, y-70);
        }
        else
        {
            context.fillText("Vy: "+vy.toFixed(2)+" m/s", x+100, y-70);
        }
    }
}
//draws the red lines that follow the projectile
function trazaraltura(vy){

    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.strokeStyle = "red";
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    altura=parseInt(y);
    alcance=parseInt(x);

    if(tiempo > 0.1)
    {
        if((x>canvas.width-100 && tiempo>11) || (x>canvas.width-100))
        {
            for (i=altura;i<canvas.height;i+=5)
            {
                if((i%2)!==0)
                {
                    context.lineTo(canvas.width-100,i);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.moveTo(canvas.width-100,i+10);
                }
            }

            for (i=0;i<alcance;i+=5)
            {
                if((i%2)!==0)
                {
                    context.lineTo(i,y);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.moveTo(i+10,y);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (i=altura;i<canvas.height;i+=5)
            {
                if((i%2)!==0)
                {
                    context.lineTo(x,i);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.moveTo(x,i+10);
                }
            }

            for (i=0;i<alcance;i+=5){
                if((i%2)!==0)
                {
                    context.lineTo(i,y);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.moveTo(i+10,y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    context.stroke();
}
//hace que solo se pueda meter numeros en el campo de angulo y velocidad
function justNumbers(e)
{
    var keynum = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : e.which;
    if ((keynum == 8) || (keynum == 46))
    return true;
    return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
}
// reinicia la animacion cuando aplasta el boton reinciar    
function fun_reiniciar(){
    document.getElementById("angulo").removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementById("velocidadin").removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementById("posx").value ="";
    document.getElementById("posy").value ="";
    document.getElementById("vx").value ="";
    document.getElementById("vy").value ="";
    document.getElementById("tiempo").value ="";
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    temp=false;

    document.getElementById("iniciar").disabled = false;

    fun_iniciar();
}
```

Comment: try using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for smoother animations - other than that, maybe someone will debug your wall of code for you, but I doubt it

Comment: @JaromandaX ill check that out, yeah I think I made the code a bit long haha.

Answer (score 0):

Using the drawing functions like rect, arc, moveTo, lineTo etc will always be slow. What you need to do is draw all the bits that do not change shape and colour onto images then draw the images rather than use the draw functions.

**Creating a drawable image.**

It is easy to create an image that you can draw to. Just create a canvas and attach the context to it. Images created like this are just as quick as Images and can be drawn very quickly onto the main canvas

```
var createImage = function(width, height){  // create a drawable image 
    var image = document.createElement("canvas");
    image.width = width;
    image.height = height;
    image.ctx = image.getContext("2d"); // create the context and attach it to the image
    return image;
}
```

**Rendering to the image**

To render to the image you do it as you do to any canvas

```
var fencePost = createImage(100,400);
fencePost.ctx.fillStyle ="White";
fencePost.ctx.strokeStyle ="Black";
fencePost.ctx.beginPath();
// the drawing stuff
fencePost.ctx.fill();
fencePost.ctx.stroke();
```

To draw the image onto the main canvas just do it like any other image.

```
var fenceWidth = 400;
// ctx is the main canvas.
for(var i = 0; i < ctx.canvas.width; i += fenceWidth){
    ctx.drawImage(fencePost, i , 400);
}
```

You also have the advantage of being able to change just the one image and as it is drawn many times you get them all to change with the one draw function.

The function `fillRect()` is about the same speed as the function `drawImage()` (if you keep the image size to fit into GPU RAM). You can get a significant speed improvement by offloading the detailed drawing to the start, and just rendering the images when you need them.

**requestAnimationFrame**

To update the animation use `requestAnimationFrame(functionName)` as it will do a much better job of keeping the frame rate constant and avoids flickering if it can, by keeping in sync with the display refersh.

```
function mainLoop(){
    // your code for the main loop


   requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); // request the next animation frame
                                    // and call mainLoop when available.
}
```